# Last child of table stylized in CSS (no classes)

Tags: css, css-tables

I'm applying a style to have every odd cell with 2px solid bottom border, and every even has 1px solid bottom border.  I want to target last child to have the 2px solid bottom. this is my code as of right now (which works except the bottom having the 2px solid.)

(please note: I am VERY new to CSS, following twitter bootstrap CSS to do what I can and adapting some of it to my site. this is my first CSS project. I know there are a lot of compatibility issues with older browsers in here, but I frankly don't care...)

```
.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-collapse: separate;
  *border-collapse: collapse;
  border-left: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
}

.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
}

.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > td,
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.table-striped 
tbody  tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid: #333;!important
}
```

Comment: The CSS is invalid and the rule may be ignored. Compare with `border-bottom: .. !important;`. Also, see what rules the *browser* is applying (is the selector matching?), and if any have applied rules have been overloaded (is another selector more specific?).

Comment: When you use bootstrap it is a good idea to leave their css alone and then just add you own stylesheet after theirs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is dirty syntax, you are using a `colon` and `!important` at wrong places, so this

```
border-bottom: 2px solid: #333;!important
                      --^-- --^--
```

Should be replaced with

```
border-bottom: 2px solid #333 !important;
```

Comment: I copy-pasted what you gave me and I'm still having the same issue. My important declaration. Should tr:last-child td { be tr:last-child { ?

Comment: any other suggestions on what could be causing it not to work?

Comment: You have also a syntax error, the : after solid. it should be solid #333 and not solid: #333

Comment: @vals Aaaa shit how did I missed that... thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is bad syntax in the statement. I would do:

```
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > td,
.table-striped tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > th {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.table-striped tbody > tr:last-child > td {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
}
```

The syntax is now correct, and it works. See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/4ZAQf/1/)

You don't need important because they have equal specifity, and the one placed last wins.

I have also changed the syntax, adding ">". It is not necesary, but I find more easy to read it afterwards if the style is consistent with the prior declarations